# iOS icon build error

Tags: ios, flutter

So I used https://github.com/franzsilva/flutter_launcher_icons to generate the icons for my flutter project- which was pretty sweet, thank you very much.

Trying to create the IOS app, I got this error:

> project/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets: error: None of the input catalogs
>   contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named 
>   "Icon-App".

I have very little knowledge of iOS development, so I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was caused by a previous release of Flutter Launcher Icons where a configuration file within the iOS project was wrongly altered whenever overwriting the default icon (whenever you set `ios: true` within the pubspec.yaml)

Check the config file here: `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`

It should be this below

```
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
```

There's two lines you'll have to change (that same line is repeated, one is for release, the other for debug)

One of the previous releases changed it to `Icon-App` instead of `AppIcon` and this is why you're experiencing the issue.

Let me know if this fixes your issue.

Apologies for the inconvenience!

Edit: This should be auto fixed in release v0.3.2 for anyone experiencing this issue.